# saber quanto que um processo esta consumindo de i/o disco

Tags: c#, io, monitoramento

tudo bem?
Eu ja consigo monitorar CPU, memoria Ram, Disco... mas, ainda não descobri uma forma de saber quanto que um processo esta gastando de disco.

Existe algum caminho em c# para isso?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, basicamente você ouvirá o cpu por uma quantidade de tempo, para fazer o cálculo, utilizando das threads para tal. Encontrei um artigo que lhe servirá para atender 100% do que precisa, inclusive com o codigo fonte disponível para sua análise, você usará as bibliotecas:

```
System.Diagnostics
System.Threading
```

link do artigo:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10258/How-to-get-CPU-usage-of-processes-and-threads